# SSRS 2012 (Report Server): DynamicHeight property not working properly when in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services

I have a chart (range bar) inside of a tablix - the tablix is grouped by ProductLine and so the chart data is specific to that group. I have the DynamicHeight property set to:

```
=cstr(CInt(Lookup(Fields!ProductLine.Value, Fields!ProductLine.Value, Fields!rowcount1.Value, "ProductLineCount"))*IIF(Parameters!SummaryInBar.Value=1, 1, .5)) & "in"
```

The end result is that all of the charts have the same height (expecting them to be based on the data in the group) - when I put the expression in a row (inside the group), I'm able to see that it is indeed calculating properly (varying values).

I have seen that there is a known issue related to this with SQL Server 2008 reporting services, but I'm on SQL 2012. Let me know if you have any additional options for me to try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue. Turns out the designer was showing them as fixed height when no page breaks, but when deployed it works. If page breaks are used, the dynamic height was working in the designer.